# c# OracleParameter throws ORA-06502

Tags: c#, oracle

I have Oracle database with following function

```
create or replace PACKAGE PCK_A IS

FUNCTION InsertPerson(
    pi_FirstName IN person.firstname%type,
    pi_LastName IN person.lastname%type,
    pi_CompanyName IN person.companyname%type,
    pi_Email IN person.emailaddress%type,
    pi_Phone IN phonenumbers.phoneno%type,
    pi_User IN user.name%type
) RETURN NUMBER;
```

The table PERSON is defined as

```
CREATE TABLE "person" ( 
  "ID" NUMBER(7,0) NOT NULL ENABLE,  
  "EMAILADDRESS" VARCHAR2(60 BYTE),
  "FIRSTNAME" VARCHAR2(50 BYTE) DEFAULT NULL, 
  "LASTNAME" VARCHAR2(50 BYTE) DEFAULT NULL, 
  "COMPANYNAME" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE) DEFAULT NULL, 
   CONSTRAINT "PK_PERSON" PRIMARY KEY ("ID"));
```

I need to call this function in C# code, so I created following method:

```
public long InsertPerson(OracleConnection connection, OracleTransaction transaction) {
  using (var cmd = connection.CreateCommand()) {
    cmd.Transaction = transaction;
    cmd.CommandText = @"begin 
                          :personId := PCK_A.InsertPerson('Name', 'Surname', 'Company', 'mail@company.com', '123456789', 'user'); 
                        end;";
    cmd.Parameters.Add("personId", OracleDbType.Decimal, ParameterDirection.ReturnValue).Size = 7;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    return ((OracleDecimal) cmd.Parameters["contactPersonId"].Value).ToInt64();
   }
}
```

This code works properly. But when I use **OracleParameter** for function parameter **ExecuteNonQuery** throws:
*Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException: 'ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small
ORA-06512: at line 2'*

Here is C# adjusted method which causes problem:

```
public long InsertPerson(OracleConnection connection, OracleTransaction transaction) {
   using (var cmd = connection.CreateCommand()) {
      cmd.Transaction = transaction;
      cmd.CommandText = @"begin 
                             :personId := PCK_A.InsertPerson(:pFirstName, 'Surname', 'Company', 'mail@company.com', '123456789', 'user'); 
                          end;";
      cmd.Parameters.Add("pFirstName", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 50, contact.FirstName, ParameterDirection.Input);
      cmd.Parameters.Add("personId", OracleDbType.Decimal, ParameterDirection.ReturnValue).Size = 7;
      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

      return ((OracleDecimal) cmd.Parameters["contactPersonId"].Value).ToInt64();
  }
```

}

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `.Size = 7;` part of this parameter. This is size in bytes, while Oracle's `NUMBER(7, 0)` doesn't reduce memory size of number, but only logically restricts possible values (i.e. it controls that values are 7 **digits** at most, not 7 **bytes**)

Comment: Thank you. I have tried that but it didn't solve the problem. It seems there is problem with parameter `pFirstName` since without it it works, even with `.Size = 7`

Comment: Are you sure that `contact.FirstName` doesn't exceed 50 bytes? Because if you use Unicode encoding, then 1 character is not equal to 1 byte, thus even 25 characters might exceed your limits

Comment: The value of `contact.FirstName` is `"M"`, so it should fit the size without problem.